# Angular Best Way to Implement Change Detection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have such a simple architecture:

```
      AppComponent
          |
          V
 SomeContainerComponent
     |    |    |
     V    V    V
     A    B    C
```

A B and C are siblings. All of them can be interacted (user can move any of them).
Currently the change strategy for SomeContainerComponent is OnPush and it calls DoCheck cycle of all its children, but I want update each child separately.

I am a litte confused with `detectChanges` and `markForCheck`. Can anyone suggest the best way to organize change detection in my situation?

All event handler such as `mousemove`, `mousedown` and others are set on the AppComponent via `@HostListener`

Link to a tiny project with the same structure:
[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-detection-problem-ccvvg?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:335-360)

Comment: Hey Alex, would love to help. What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Are A, B and C components or class properties?

Comment: Hey, thanks. A, B and C are components

Comment: The problem is that if I interact with A Component and update it, all other components (B and C in described above case) are checked too, and that slows my app down.

Comment: Ah I see. It sounds like the data is being propagated to all components instead of each at a time. This could be triggering change detection. Hard to tell without the code.

Comment: The project is very hard coded, so it would be difficult to transfer relevant portions of code. The question is that, is there any way to perform change detection (and change applying to component's view as well) without calling change detection of its siblings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217399/discussion-between-alex-teexone-and-jburtondev).